# How to get two Docker compose files to talk to each other?

Tags: wordpress, docker, docker-compose

I am running Docker compose version 3.9, on Windows 10, running WordPress along with MySQL and PHP.  **Running all of my services from a single docker-compose.yml file works perfectly for me.**

**Here is my issue** - I want to try to run this project as 2 separate docker-compose yml files in parallel, But WordPress is complaining about when I go to the browser.  Here are my steps...

I successfully have a docker compose yml file up and running right now that consists of my MySQL and phpmyadmin services...

```yaml
        version: '3.9'
        
        services:
          # Database
          db:
            image: mysql:5.7
            volumes:
              - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
            restart: always
            environment:
              MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
              MYSQL_DATABASE: klewis
              MYSQL_USER: klewis
              MYSQL_PASSWORD: klewis
            networks:
              - wpsite
          # phpmyadmin
          phpmyadmin:
            depends_on:
              - db
            image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
            restart: always
            ports:
              - '8080:80'
            environment:
              PMA_HOST: db
              MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
            networks:
              - wpsite
        networks:
          wpsite:
        volumes:
          db_data:
```

I then created a second docker-compose yml file, in another folder environment, with just my WordPress service like so (I apologize if my splitting out the code into this file is wrong - I'm still learning that too!)...

```yaml
    version: '3.9'
    
    services:
      # don't need db or phpmyadmin loaded here because its already running on another instance!
      # Wordpress
      wordpress:
        depends_on:
          - db
        image: wordpress:latest
        ports:
          - '5939:80'
        restart: always
        volumes: ['./wp:/var/www/html']
        environment:
          WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db:3306
          WORDPRESS_DB_USER: hc
          WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: hc
          WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: hc202107
        networks:
          - wpsite
    networks:
      wpsite:
    volumes:
      db_data:
```

But when I run this 2nd compose file, and go to the browser, WordPress is showing me the following error :

[image]

What am I missing or doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify `external: true` on your network. If you don't, you'll actually get two separate networks: `project1_wpsite` and `project2_wpsite`.

Change both docker-compose files to include external like this

```
   networks:
      wpsite:
         external: true
```

You'll need to manually create the network before you start your docker-compose configurations using `docker network create wpsite`.

Comment: Your instructions worked perfectly.  That was a first time exposure for me in creating a docker network to bridge them together.  I am now also able to inspect the network and see it in both environments through my terminal.  Many thanks.